# How do I gracefully shutdown mongoose's connection pool?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

If I receive a SIGINT/SIGTERM (e.g. ctrl+c) then I must *gracefully* stop my app and close all connections to the mongodb server.

Most documentation/tutorials state that to stop a connection (or 
pool of connections), I must use [`mongoose.disconnect()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-disconnect) - which calls [`.close()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-close) on connections in the pool.

However all those docs also say this should be done *after all pending writes are completed*.

How can I know this when I receive a signal event (e.g. SIGINT, SIGTERM, etc.)? Does mongoose have graceful shutdown functionality, or will I lose data when I call  `disconnect()`?

(I'm using the latest bits.)

Comment: I know how to listen for signal events. What I don't know is how to ensure all writes are flushed. How to do so **gracefully**, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one;

```js
process.on ("SIGINT", async() => {
  await mongoose.connection.close ();
  process.exit (0)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To receive SIGINT signal and stop a connection you can use following code:

```js
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    mongoose.disconnect().then(() => {
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I know how to do that. The question is how do I do so gracefully - if at all possible - so that pending writes are not lost.

Comment: It will not force closing connection.

Comment: `process.exit()` is a fail-fast approach

Comment: But will be invoked after mongoose.disconnect() return RESOLVED promise...